# categorize data based on multiple rows in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a data of student which has various study and performance improvement. There will be 4 studies and the performance data of the student for each study will be recorded based on 5 days.

Below is the link for the table script and values.

[image: Data]

[Script Link](http://rextester.com/BYFM9032)

I want to categorize the student in such a way that *if the performance in any two of the study is worse then it has to be worse, if there is no improvement in any 3 of the studies then it has to be no-improvement else it has to be improvement*.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
select StudentNumber
        ,case when sum(case when Performance = 'Worsening' then 1 else 0 end) >= 2
                then 'Worsening'
                else case when sum(case when Performance = 'Improvement' then 1 else 0 end) >= 3
                            then 'Improvement'
                            else 'No Improvement'
                            end
                end as Performance
from tbl_student
group by StudentNumber
```